# What is POSIX awk's stance on null byte in variables/printf?

Tags: awk, posix, standard

Is it legal to print null bytes using awk's `printf` function according to POSIX? The [POSIX standard of `awk`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) does not seem to explicitly mention it either way. Real world implementations differ in how they behave:

```
+$ gawk 'BEGIN { x = sprintf("\000"); print(length(x)); }'
1
+$ busybox awk 'BEGIN { x = sprintf("\000"); print(length(x)); }'
0
+$
```

and

```
+$ gawk 'BEGIN { printf("\000"); }' | xxd
00000000: 00                                       .
+$ busybox awk 'BEGIN { printf("\000"); }' | xxd
+$
```

Is this specified somewhere in the standard? If yes, is the behaviour required for variables (`x = sprintf("\000")`) and printf (`printf("\000")`) same?

Comment: I take it from the prompt’s you’re a vi-mode user in bash. Nice to find a friend :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are at least 4 relevant pieces of text in [the POSIX.2018 specification of `awk`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/awk.html):

Emphasis (bold text) is mine in all the quoted text below:

> Input files to the awk program from any of the following sources shall be **text** files

That means that if the input contains NUL characters (which would make it non-text as per the POSIX definition of text), then the behaviour is unspecified.

> \ddd : A <backslash> character followed by the longest sequence
>         of one, two, or three octal-digit characters (01234567).
>         **If all of the digits are 0 (that is, representation of
>         the NUL character), the behavior is undefined**.

So `\000` results in undefined behaviour.

About regexp matching:

> However, in all awk ERE
>        matching, **the use of one or more NUL characters in the pattern, input record, or text string produces undefined results**

About `printf`/`sprintf`:

> 7. For the c conversion specifier character: if the argument has a numeric value, the character whose encoding is that value
>            shall be output. **If the value is zero** or is not the encoding of any character in the character set, **the behavior is
>            undefined**.

So, that's another way to get a NUL character that leads to undefined behaviour.

So, to sum up, in `awk`, POSIX tells us you can't use the NUL character portably, whether it's for input, output or to store in its variables.

`gawk` (since at least 2.10 in 1989 which is the earliest version I could find where [NUL support is documented](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/gawk-info?h=gawk-2.10#n3100)) and [@ThomasDickey's `mawk`](https://invisible-island.net/mawk/) (since [version 20140914](https://invisible-island.net/mawk/CHANGES.html#t20140914)) are two implementations that can deal with NUL.

Comment: gawk still is NOT safe to use with data containing NUL-chars. When using string with NUL-chars as files or commands, they will SILENTLY decay into zero-terminated strings. `printf 'foo\0bar' | gawk '{print $0 > $0}'`.

Comment: @pizdelect, yes, but in that case, it's not `gawk`'s fault. File names or command arguments or environment variables (name and values) can't contain NUL characters. It's up to you the `gawk` user to deal with it as appropriate, there's nothing that `gawk` can do to magically fix it (though I'd agree with your *SILENTLY* objection, that it could be nice if it reported those cases). `zsh` can also deal with `NUL`, but in a similar way it will break when using APIs (`execve()`, `open()`...) that can't handle them.

Answer (score -6):

C-strings in general cannot contain nul bytes and `awk` basically is some kind of C interpreter. A POSIX utility that is able to print nul bytes would need to be explicitly mentioned in the POSIX standard. `printf` in `awk` is not such a case.

The following cases are explicitly listed in POSIX:

```
echo 'x\0000y'
printf 'x\000y\n'
printf '%b\n' 'x\0000y'
```

all three commands print four characters on a certified OS with POSIX UNIX branding.

Your `awk` examples are using unspecified behavior.

Comment: "`awk` basically is some kind of C interpreter" It is not.

Comment: The three usecases also print 4 characters in NetBSD with `ksh` . Besides the ambiguity of the "C interpreter" phrasing, why the six (!) downvotes?

Comment: These are most likely from Linux people that do not know that the `XSI` enhancements to `echo` are required for a `POSIX UNIX` branding and that platforms that do not implement `XSI` at best may get a POSIX certification for `small embedded platforms`.